# Should I link thousands on landing pages to my website or not?

Tags: seo, landing-page

I'm working on a website, recently we decided to create thousands of landing pages to target different cities, using different keywords and feed them to google ... 
Our website's google rank is quite good ! question is, should we have these landing pages in our website's structure or have them separate not directly linked to the website ? if we do that is it going to damage our reputation?

Comment: Downvotes seem a bit excessive...

Answer (score 2):

That's ok to do although you probably will run into issues with duplicate content. Pages like what you're describing tend to have the same content with the exception of city/location names. There just isn't enough different content on the pages to have them be considered original content.

I would also place them on your website as having thousands of mini-sites linked to your main site sounds like something that may be considered a linking scheme. That's a big no-no and you run the risk of penalties or being banned.

Answer (score 0):

If the landing pages provide different content to each city then I think you should keep them within your sites structure and use internal links between them all.

If you have literally just called pages city_x.html and city_y.html then I am sure Google will catch on and catch up with you soon enough, I would say pull them off altogether before you are punished for it.